# Função retorna ponteiro para lixo, e free trava o terminal

Tags: c, ponteiro

Alguém poderia me explicar o motivo de quando eu dou `free` no `pontaux` o terminal do Windows para de responder? E por que quando aloco o `pontmaior` meu resultado vem como lixo de memória?

A função retorna um ponteiro para o maior valor de um vetor.

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* retornamaior (int *vetor, int tamanho) {

    int i, maior = vetor[0];

    for (i=0; i<tamanho; i++) {
        if (vetor[i]>=maior)
            maior = vetor[i];   
        }

    int *pontmaior = &maior;

    return pontmaior;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int *vetor, tamanho, i;

    printf ("Digite o tamanho da sequência: ");
    scanf ("%d", &tamanho);

    vetor = (int*)malloc(tamanho*sizeof(int));

    printf ("Digite a sequência: ");

    for (i=0; i<tamanho; i++)
        scanf ("%d", &vetor[i]);

    int *pontaux = retornamaior (vetor,tamanho);

    printf ("Maior: %d\n", *pontaux);

    free (vetor);

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Kay, não quero ser fanboy, mas C++ faz tudo isso em ~12 linhas...

Comment: hehehe, mas to aprendendo C por enquanto :D

Comment: Isso, garoto, comecei assim mesmo :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O erro parece estar aqui:

```
int *pontmaior = &maior;
```

Você está retornando um ponteiro para a variável de pilha "maior", que nem existe mais quando é utilizada pelo main().

Você deveria retornar um simples inteiro apontando qual item da matriz "vetor" é o maior. É mais seguro, evita esse monte de manipulações de ponteiro.

Ficaria algo assim:

```
int retornamaior (int *vetor, int tamanho)
{
        int i, maior = 0;
        for (i=0; i<tamanho; i++) {
                if (vetor[i]>=vetor[maior])
                        maior = i;
        }
        return maior;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int *vetor, tamanho, i;

        printf ("Digite o tamanho da sequência: ");
        scanf ("%d", &tamanho);

        vetor = (int*)malloc(tamanho*sizeof(int));

        printf ("Digite a sequência: ");

        for (i=0; i<tamanho; i++)
                scanf ("%d", &vetor[i]);

        int pontaux = retornamaior (vetor,tamanho);

        printf ("Maior: %d\n", vetor[pontaux]);

        free (vetor);

        return 0;
}
```

Se você faz questão de retornar um ponteiro:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* retornamaior (int *vetor, int tamanho) {

    int i, *maior = &vetor[0];

    for (i=0; i<tamanho; i++) {
        if (vetor[i]>=*maior)
            maior = &vetor[i];
        }

    return maior;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int *vetor, tamanho, i;

    printf ("Digite o tamanho da sequência: ");
    scanf ("%d", &tamanho);

    vetor = (int*)malloc(tamanho*sizeof(int));

    printf ("Digite a sequência: ");

    for (i=0; i<tamanho; i++)
        scanf ("%d", &vetor[i]);

    int *pontaux = retornamaior (vetor,tamanho);

    printf ("Maior: %d\n", *pontaux);

    free (vetor);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Desculpa minha ignorância, mas ainda não sei o que é pilha. Como eu poderia apontar um ponteiro pro maior? Só me veio essa forma em mente.

Comment: Variável em pilha é aquele tipo de variável "normal" que você declara normalmente no início da função. Vou mudar minha resposta para você ver como ficaria a função no estilo sugerido

Comment: Entendi, mas nesse caso a função não estaria retornando estaticamente o "maior" número? Eu preciso retornar um ponteiro. É possível fazer isso sem apresentar os erros que estavam dando?

Comment: Sim, você poderia fazer a variável "maior" ser um ponteiro, e atribuir a ela o ponteiro &vetor[i], que não perde a validate até o free(). A comparação teria de ser if (vetor[i] >= *maior).

Comment: int *pontmaior = &maior? Existe outra forma de fazer isso? Obrigado pela paciência, mas é que essa parte ainda tá meio complicado pra mim.

Comment: Editei de novo, adicionando uma segunda solução que retorna ponteiro.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Entendi o que estava fazendo errado, novamente obrigado pela paciência :).

Comment: Blz, não esqueça do +1 na resposta para indicar que a pergunta está devidamente respondida.

Comment: Bem, já tentei mas aparece que não tenho pontos suficientes de reputação pra dar um +1.

Comment: Vc já confirmou a resposta, está perfeito!

Comment: Kay, apenas para constar. Não sei qual seu entendimento sobre ponteiros, mas lembre-se que o ponteiro retornado é apenas o endereço para determinada posição no array. Se o valor dessa posição mudar `*pontaux` muda. Mas isso não significa que você sempre terá um ponteiro para a maior posição do array. Estou dizendo isso pois esse parece muito com um exercício clássico de ponteiros de função (que são um outro mamute).

Comment: Hum, mas isso era pra minha solução né? E com a segunda solução ali do epx também nem sempre retornará um ponteiro pra maior posição? Sim, eu entendo um pouco de ponteiros, no caso da minha função ele tá retornando o endereço pra onde o valor está armazenada, né? 
A única coisa que eu mudei foi alocar o ponteiro maior e depois definir *maior = vetor[0];

Comment: Acho que o que ele quis dizer foi que se o conteúdo do array mudar depois de você calcular o maior, é possível que o ponteiro não esteja mais apontando para o maior elemento, teria que calcular novamente.

Answer (score 3):

Vi a resposta do epx e percebi que se perdeu um pouco para entender o porquê do seguinte trecho de código

```
int *pontmaior = &maior;
```

estar errado, o que acontece é que quando você declara `int *pointmaior` dentro da sua função você está declarando uma variável que só vai existir dentro do escopo da função `int* retornamaior (int *vetor, int tamanho)`, os seja, a área de memória destinada a essa variável vai ser liberada pelo sistema ao término da execução dessa função, sendo assim, ao se executar a linha

```
printf ("Maior: %d\n", *pontaux);
```

você já tentará acessar uma área inválida de memória.

Comment: O conteúdo é relevante o suficiente para ser uma resposta complementar.

Comment: O pontaux não vai receber o endereço da memória da função retornamaior? Nesse caso eu to imprimindo o pontaux e não o pontmaior.

Comment: Se entendi direito sua pergunta a resposta é sim, vai, o problema é que essa memória já foi liberada para ser usada em outra coisa ao sair da função 'retornamaior' e isso acontece porque você está retornando um ponteiro que referencia a variável 'maior' declarada dentro da função 'retornamaior' e como um ponteiro guarda o endereço de uma variável e não seu valor o ponteiro 'pontmaior' vai receber um endereço de memória inválido.

Comment: @Kay, uma variável declarada dentro de uma função é chamada de variável **local**. O motivo dela ter este nome é simples: ela só vai existir enquanto a função estiver executando; ela só vai poder ser acessada localmente pela função onde está declarada (ou por funções chamadas por essa funçao). Ou seja, quando você chama a função `retornamaior`, antes da função executar, o programa reserva um espaço de memória para aquelas variáveis, e quando a função termina de executar, esse espaço de memória não é mais reservado e pode ser usado posteriormente por outra função, para outra funcionalidade.

Comment: Por isso, se você retorna um ponteiro para uma variável local de uma função, você não pode lidar com esse ponteiro **depois** da função ter terminado de executar. Entendeu?

Comment: Acho que sim. Por exemplo, se a variável 'maior' estivesse como parâmetro da função, o endereço dessa variável poderia ser usada na main? Porque já fiz exemplos assim.

Comment: Kay, me parece que te falta um pouco de conceito de escopo de variável em C, basicamente escopo de uma variável é o local da aplicação, onde esta pode ser vista e alterada (Fonte: http://www.portaleducacao.com.br/informatica/artigos/6359/escopo-e-vida-util-de-variaveis-vbnet#ixzz2t40N1zH9).

Comment: Separei esses 2 links que dão uma idéia melhor de escopo em C: http://www.di.ufpb.br/liliane/aulas/escopo.html, http://linguagemc.com.br/funcoes-e-escopo-de-variaveis/

Comment: @Kay, se você declarar como parâmetro **sem ser um ponteiro**, não. Nesse caso, acontece mesma coisa. Ela é alocada no começo da execução da função e desalocada no final. Se o seu exemplo funcionou, foi só coincidência. Porque acessar uma área inválida de memória em C/C++ possui um comportamento não determinado. Ou seja, **não necessariamente** gera um erro de execução, mas pode ser que gere sim.

Comment: Entendi, vou procurar dar uma estudada mais nessa parte. Realmente é um pouco confuso.